# How to group an array and make form to display in Chart?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to create a array to display in a chart,

This are my data:

```
[
  { Cantidad: 2, Mesint: 4, DepartmentName: 'CALIDAD' },
  { Cantidad: 1, Mesint: 5, DepartmentName: 'CALIDAD' },
  { Cantidad: 2, Mesint: 3, DepartmentName: 'GERENCIA' },
  { Cantidad: 1, Mesint: 4, DepartmentName: 'MATERIALES' },
  { Cantidad: 1, Mesint: 6, DepartmentName: 'MATERIALES' },
  { Cantidad: 9, Mesint: 1, DepartmentName: 'PRODUCCION' },
  { Cantidad: 23, Mesint: 2, DepartmentName: 'PRODUCCION' },
  { Cantidad: 6, Mesint: 3, DepartmentName: 'PRODUCCION' },
  { Cantidad: 22, Mesint: 4, DepartmentName: 'PRODUCCION' },
  { Cantidad: 16, Mesint: 5, DepartmentName: 'PRODUCCION' },
  { Cantidad: 4, Mesint: 6, DepartmentName: 'PRODUCCION' },
  { Cantidad: 3, Mesint: 3, DepartmentName: 'PRUEBA ELECTRICA' },
  { Cantidad: 2, Mesint: 4, DepartmentName: 'PRUEBA ELECTRICA' },
  { Cantidad: 1, Mesint: 5, DepartmentName: 'PRUEBA ELECTRICA' },
  { Cantidad: 1, Mesint: 6, DepartmentName: 'PRUEBA ELECTRICA' },
  { Cantidad: 1, Mesint: 6, DepartmentName: 'TI' },
];
```

And need this group form:
Output

```
[
  { name: 'CALIDAD', data: [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
  { name: 'GERENCIA', data: [0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
  { name: 'MATERIALES', data: [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
  { name: 'PRODUCCION', data: [9, 23, 6, 22, 16, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
  { name: 'PRUEBA ELECTRICA', data: [0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
  { name: 'TI', data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] },
];
```

The array into previous group form is a array with "Cantidad" filter with Mesint, this a reference to mounths of year. So i need put 0 when the "head" (for example: "Calidad") doesnt have a value.

I'm trying group with map(), but i can't push the array with count (Value/"Cantidad") in month.

Comment: Please share your attempt with `map()` by editing the question. Also, both your data and output aren't valid.

Comment: I'm not sure `map` is a good idea because the expected array is grouped by `DepartmentName` while `map` will returns an array of the entities (no matter you'll do in the map). Quick indication is that `map` will ever returns an array with the same count of items as the source, 16 in your case, while you want an array with 6 items. My suggestion is to use create a new array, loop for month and fill it based on the "current" month inside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, note that the expected output you have describe isn't valid, an [Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics) should consist of `key/value` pairs. However, you can generate an object where the `keys` are the `DepartmentName's` and the values are the array of `Cantidad` for the `12` months:

```
{
  "CALIDAD": [0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  "GERENCIA": [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  "MATERIALES": [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  "PRODUCCION": [9,23,6,22,16,4,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  "PRUEBA ELECTRICA": [0,0,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0],
  "TI": [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]
}
```

That output will be similar to the one you expect and can be achieved using [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), like shown on the next example:

```js
const input = [
  {Cantidad: 2, Mesint: 4, DepartmentName: "CALIDAD"},
  {Cantidad: 1, Mesint: 5, DepartmentName: "CALIDAD"},
  {Cantidad: 2, Mesint: 3, DepartmentName: "GERENCIA"},
  {Cantidad: 1, Mesint: 4, DepartmentName: "MATERIALES"},
  {Cantidad: 1, Mesint: 6, DepartmentName: "MATERIALES"},
  {Cantidad: 9, Mesint: 1, DepartmentName: "PRODUCCION"},
  {Cantidad: 23, Mesint: 2, DepartmentName: "PRODUCCION"},
  {Cantidad: 6, Mesint: 3, DepartmentName: "PRODUCCION"},
  {Cantidad: 22, Mesint: 4, DepartmentName: "PRODUCCION"},
  {Cantidad: 16, Mesint: 5, DepartmentName: "PRODUCCION"},
  {Cantidad: 4, Mesint: 6, DepartmentName: "PRODUCCION"},
  {Cantidad: 3, Mesint: 3, DepartmentName: "PRUEBA ELECTRICA"},
  {Cantidad: 2, Mesint: 4, DepartmentName: "PRUEBA ELECTRICA"},
  {Cantidad: 1, Mesint: 5, DepartmentName: "PRUEBA ELECTRICA"},
  {Cantidad: 1, Mesint: 6, DepartmentName: "PRUEBA ELECTRICA"},
  {Cantidad: 1, Mesint: 6, DepartmentName: "TI"}
];

let res = input.reduce((acc, {Cantidad, Mesint, DepartmentName}) =>
{
    acc[DepartmentName] = acc[DepartmentName] || [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    acc[DepartmentName][Mesint - 1] = Cantidad;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log(res);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

If the generated output don't meet your goal, you can use the example as a guide and adapt it to your needs. For example, if you want something like next:

```
[
  {name: "CALIDAD", data: [0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
  {name: "GERENCIA", data: [0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
  {name: "MATERIALES", data: [0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
  {name: "PRODUCCION", data: [9,23,6,22,16,4,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
  {name: "PRUEBA ELECTRICA", data: [0,0,3,2,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]},
  {name: "TI", data: [0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0]}
]
```

Then, you can use next code after the `.reduce()` method

```
res = Object.entries(res).map(([name, data]) => ({name, data}));
```

Comment: I'm sorry really i want to structure with this form. [ name:"CALIDAD", data:[0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], need i only add the key?

Comment: If you want an array of objects as output where objects are of the form `{name: "CALIDAD", data: [0,0,0,2,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}`, then you can map the **entries** of the object generated with `.reduce()`. Check the final section of the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you a lot, now i can understand more about the manipulation of objects.